# Swift: Cannot swap elements in an array

Tags: xcode, swift

G'day All,

I am trying to shuffle a deck of cards.  My algorithm is to step through the deck and swap each card with a randomly selected card.  At this stage I am just trying to swap a known card with a randomly selected one.  The build fails at the swap line even though I can access the array and retrieve each card.

The function looks like:

```
    func shuffle() ->[String]{
    let deck = ["AS","2S","3S","4S","5S","6S","7S","8S","9S","10S","JS","QS","KS"]

    var i = 12
    var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))

    println("The card for \(i) is \(deck[i])")
    println("The card for \(j) is \(deck[j])")

    swap(&deck[i], &deck[j])

    return deck

}
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(inout inout $T6, inout inout $T11)'
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Ta,

Comment: deck is a constant, change let to var

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 try this:

```
deck.swapAt(i, j)
```